# Conway's Game of Life borders rules

Tags: algorithms

I'm taking a look at the Conway's Game of Life rules, and I'm not sure how to deal when the cell reach the corner of the field... let's take an example:

```
x x x x x x
x x o x x x
x x o x x x
x x o x x x
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
```

in this case the next lifecycle would be the following:

```
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
x o o o x x
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
```

But what happens when I have a case like this:

```
x x x x x x
x x x x x o
x x x x x o
x x x x x o
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
```

The cells reached the corner of everything, should I make it pass to the other side? like this:

```
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
o x x x o o
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
```

or consider the cells on the right as always dead?

Comment: Aren't the rules for the game of life generally played on an infinite grid?  There is no "side" or "corner" on an infinite grid.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life

Comment: This is a classic problem encountered by people looking to implement Conway's Game of Life into a computer program. And it's actually up to the programmer to decide what happens. If you're taking a programming class, it would be best to ask your professor. They might impose the extra programming challenge for you to wrap the cells around the board, but on most examples I witnessed, usually the cells off the board died.

Comment: Conway wanted to construct the rules in such a way that it cannot be decided whether a particular cell lives forever. For this, he needed an infinite board. Of course, a computer can only simulate a game on a finite board. The rules are the same as described for an infinite board. But as I understood, cells on the "other side" are not considered to be neighbours.

Comment: @JMoravitz makes sense, according to wikipedia it's infinite indeed.

Comment: @Peter yeah, I'm not sure if I should consider the "other side" cells as neighbors as well...

Comment: @pyrazolam thanks man! I'll try to set a challenge to myself and maybe implement it in both ways...

Still I'm curious about the border rules...

Comment: @Peter: a computer can perfectly simulate a game on an infinite board, as long as you don't try to evaluate it on an infinite amount of cells.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there are no official border rules because Conway designed the game for an infinite grid. As such there are no borders to make rules about.

If you are implementing this as a computer program and you want to give the illusion of an infinite grid that goes on beyond the user's view, you must design the program so that it updates more cells than are currently visible to the user. The data component of your program might be implemented as a 500 x 500 array even though you are only drawing the middle 300 x 300 to the screen. Any cells beyond the 500 x 500 grid would be permanently dead for the sake of your program.

This is analogous to what computers do when working with real numbers. There is a certain amount of precision that is limited by hardware, yet that precision may be much greater than what is displayed to the user at the end of a calculation, especially if the number of decimals is fixed to the size of a display.

At some point, the decimal expansion of a number must be rounded off, but for instance a calculator can give the illusion of having unlimited information to a naive user who divides by 1000 and sees new digits of pi come from the abyss.

Comment: Unlike the decimal expansion of $\pi$, the board after a finite number of moves has only a finite number of elements. If you really want to "do it right", it is possible to design the data structures and algorithms such that when cells need to be created "off the edge" the data structure extends to fit them. Of course, eventually, if you have too many occupied cells you'll run out of memory. But I have a hunch you'll decide the program has run long enough before that happens.

Comment: Completing David K's comment: to compute precisely the state of a cell at time t, you need to know the states of every cell in a square of length 2t-1 at time 0, that's $O(t^2)$ initial states, and $O(t^3)$ intermediate states to compute. so even computing 10k iterations may be costly (as long as you don't use fancy techniques).